# Strange behaviour of \pstTriangle

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

When I compile the following code with `etex` , `dvips` and `ps2pdf`, I have a strange output:

```
\input pstricks.tex
\input pst-eucl.tex

{ \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](0,0)(1,0) }
\hskip2cm
\pstTriangle(0,0){A}(1,0){B}(1,1){C}  % normal

\vskip2cm

\psline[linewidth=0.2pt](0,0)(1,0)
\hskip2cm
\pstTriangle(0,0){A}(1,0){B}(1,1){C} % strange

\end
```

`\pstTriangle` is a command of `pst-eucl`.

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the strange thing is that `pst-eucl` uses the linewidth set by `psline` in the second example?

Comment: Note that I can't reproduce the behavior on my system, the lines in the second triangle are the same width as in the first triangle. Maybe a viewer issue, which viewers did you try?

Comment: @Marijn: Have you the latest versions of `pstricks` and `pst-eucl`?

Comment: I don't have the latest versions, `pstricks` is 2.82 (2018-01-06) and `pst-eucl` is 1.56 (2017-04-18).

Comment: @Marijn: Maybe this is a bug in more recent versions of `pst-eucl`.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'll investigate ...

Comment: I get the same result in TeXLive 2020 (updated), using `etex` and `xetex`

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug and it has been corrected in the version 1.72 of `pst-eucl`.